# bad access when storing double in pointer -- llvm IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In the following code what I try to do is load an array of doubles (represented as a pointer) from a nested struct inside a struct then store a value inside the final element. When I try to execute this, I get a segmentation fault (debugging below). Why am I getting a segmentation fault and how can I fix it?

#### LLVM IR Code

```
  %7 = getelementptr { { double*, i32 }*, i32 }, { { double*, i32 }*, i32 }* %foo3, i32 0, i32 0
  %load_array_ptr = load { double*, i32 }*, { double*, i32 }** %7
  %8 = getelementptr { double*, i32 }, { double*, i32 }* %load_array_ptr, i32 0, i32 0
  %load_elem_ptr = load double*, double** %8
  %9 = getelementptr double, double* %load_elem_ptr, i32 0
  ; problematic line:
  store double 1.000000e+00, double* %9
```

#### Debugging

I tried debugging this with lldb but, I did not really get anything useful:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000ee9 built`__anon_expr0 + 105
built`__anon_expr0:
->  0x100000ee9 <+105>: movsd  %xmm0, (%rax)
    0x100000eed <+109>: movsd  0x10(%rsp), %xmm0         ; xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    0x100000ef3 <+115>: addq   $0x48, %rsp
    0x100000ef7 <+119>: retq
Target 0: (built) stopped.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
> ```

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means you're illegally accessing memory and `address=0x0` means that the address you're trying to access is 0. So, if this occurs on `store double 1.000000e+00, double* %9`, `%9` must be a null pointer. This means that the `double*` in your inner array was null.

PS:

> ```
> %9 = getelementptr double, double* %load_elem_ptr, i32 0
> ```

This isn't related to your problem, but here you're setting `%9` to be equal to `%load_elem_ptr + 0`, which is a no-op.

Comment: Thanks - I was able to find where the error was based on that. Why is `%9` a no-op? Isn't that how you get the first element of an array in pointer form? That is what I got when I compiled some c code.

Comment: @pudility It's a no-op because you're adding 0 to the pointer and adding 0 is a no-op. But you're right, it's perfectly normal to generate code like this when accessing the index 0 of something. As you say, C compilers generate the same thing before optimization and once you apply `opt` to it, it's gonna disappear anyway. I didn't really take into account that the code was generated when making that comment.